# What is the advantage of using stored procedures to do insert/update/delete/select?

Tags: database, jdbc

I am currently looking at some code that is doing even trivial insert/select/update by running stored procedures.

So the code basically does

```
CallableStatememt stm= jdbcConnection.prepareCall(sp_name with ??) ;
stm.setParameters()
stm.execute();
```

As I said before the code behint sp_name is mostly trivial. No multi table inserts or complicated calculations.

Are there any benefits against just doing

```
Statement stm = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(insert_query)
stm.setParameters();
stm.execute();
```

where `insert_query`is a 'normal' *single* INSERT / SELECT / ... statement?

Comment: Stored Procedures are just a RDBMS's way of doing encapsulation. The same arguments apply as they do to any form of encapsulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three main performance advantages come to mind:
1. The string sent to the SQL Server is shorter
2. That makes the parsing time shorter
3. The execution plan is ready in advance

Although seemingly trivial, the latter point can be significant; checking that objects exist, the correct number of fields, etc.

Overall, however, I'd say those only matter when being called many many times in succession.

A more significant advantage, in my opinion, is an engineering one; Encapsulation.

In the future, you may decide to add logging, or consistency checks, business logic, or anything.  By encapsulating it in an SP, it will only ever need revising in one place.

Comment: Personally, I believe that a database should be treated as a stand-alone self supporting remote object.  One doesn't allow direct access to properties of an Object in Java/C#, and nor should one do so in a database.  This has it's own difficulties, but they have always (in my experience) been less than the difficulties caused by allowing apps have direct access to tables.

Comment: PreparedStatements also should have the pre-parsing. And the execution plan shouldn't that be compiled at the time of statement execution, as it may vary depending on the data already in the database (index scan vs. full table scan for example)?

Comment: The prepare statement version is effectively creating a short term stored procedure, specifically for the current connection/session.  The preparation of this involves a level of parsing and compilation each time the app calls prepareStatement.  With SPs that's done when the SP is created.  The RDBMS may recompile the SP as the table statistics change, but this is certainly less often than the prepareStatement version.

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure is a precompiled executable object that contains one or more SQL statements.Since, stored procedures are precompiled objects they execute faster at the database server. Most of the time, stored procedures contain more than one command;

See more here :

- [Insert-update-delete vs Stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478234/which-method-is-best-method-for-speed-in-sql-server-stored-procedure)

More on Stored procedures :

- [Advantages and Disadvantages of Stored Procedures](http://mukund.wordpress.com/2005/10/14/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-stored-procedure/)

Answer (score 1):

The main advantages of using Stored Procedure are:

1. All the sql commands in the SP will execute together or none will get executed. This ensures atomicity. All sql commands in SP are in transaction scope.
2. SPs are much faster than normal sql commands. SPs are compiled and optimized by the DB by creating proper execution plan.
3. control flow statements like IF-ELSE and loops like FOR can be used in SPs but not in sql queries. This saves lot of data being fetched in the DAO and then processing the data.
4. Reduces network traffic as only required data is transmitted though the network.
5. Modularises the code of the SP as it helps in reusability and helps to maintain the logic.